# ¿Cómo ejecutar un método heredado al interno de una clase?

Tags: python-3.x, clase, herencia

A modo de ejemplo de lo que busco lograr he creado una clase Persona que hereda de Habla:

```
class Habla:
    def expresion(frase, grita):
        if grita:
            return frase.upper()
        else:
            return frase

class Persona(Habla):
    def __init__(self, frase, grita):
        self.grita = grita
        self.frase = super().expresion(frase, grita)

persona = Persona(frase="Aghh!", grita=True)
```

El problema que tengo es que recibo un error al ejecutar el método `expresion` de la clase Habla.

Recibo el error: `TypeError: expresion() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Sospecho que el parámetro `self` esté implicado en el asunto, pero desconozco la causa.

Probé con el debug pero no encontré en que momento se le pasan 3 parámetros al método `expresion`.

Gracias anticipadamente por cualquier explicación que puedan darme. Recalco que mi objetivo es poder ejecutar un método heredado al interno de una clase y que me gustaría saber porqué recibo ese error.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, si efectivamente se esta enviando el `self` que recibes en el constructor al metodo `expresion`, el error que te lanzo basicamente dice que el metodo recibe solo dos parametros pero 3 fueron enviados, al ser un bounded method se esta enviando por parametro el objeto que recibes en el constructor

Comment: Hola PySanti, entonces es como sospechaba. En otras palabras ¿estoy obligado a añadir el parámetro `self` a `expresion` aunque pertenezca a una clase diferente y este parámetro no sea utilizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondere sólo a la consulta formal.

El código es incorrecto (no compila). Lo corregi lo mínimo para responder a la pregunta:

```
class Habla:
    def expresion(self, frase, grita):
        if grita:
            return frase.upper()
        else:
            return frase

class Persona(Habla):
    def __init__(self, frase, grita):
        self.grita = grita
        self.frase = self.expresion(frase, grita)

a = Persona("hola", True)
print(a.frase)
```

produce:

```
HOLA
```

**Explicación**

La clase Persona desciende de Habla, por lo que `expresion` pasa a ser un método propio.

Los métodos propios de una clase se llaman usando `self`:

```
self.frase = self.expresion(frase, grita)
```

**Lectura recomendada**

Esta pregunta tiene demasiados problemas de concepto e implementación. Recomiendo revisar [Herencia en Python](https://ellibrodepython.com/herencia-en-python) para ver como se implementa correcta este tipo de soluciones.

Comment: Gracias Candid, es cierto. No me recordaba más de esto. Me conviene dar un repaso. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Tome como ejemplo el siguiente código y haga que reciba siempre "self".

```
class Habla:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def expresion(self, frase, grita):
        if grita:
            return frase.isupper()
        else:
            return frase

class Persona(Habla):
    def __init__(self, _frase, _grita):
        self.grita = _grita
        self.frase = _frase
        super().expresion(self.frase, self.grita)

persona = Persona(_frase=“Aghh!”, _grita=True)
print(persona.grita, persona.frase)
```

Espero le valga. Es importante "jugar" con self para que Python pueda referenciar sus clases.

Saludos!